# Issue with jquery-ui-rails Sprockets::FileNotFound

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

Issue trying to use jquery-ui-rails autocomplete. (Sprockets::FileNotFound)

Error:

`ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/autocomplete'`

Application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Application.css:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
```

My Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

I ran bundle. I have version 5.0.0 of jquery-ui-rails. I restarted the server. I don't know what else to try. I don't get why this isn't working? Rails 4.1.1/Ruby 2.1

I'm using RubyMine so I can command+click to the file and it is where it is supposed to be. Any ideas what else I can try? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it. The problem was that I had defined `'jquery-ui-rails'` in my gemfile before 
`'jquery-rails'`

**Gemfile order is important!**

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

Restart server. Running good! :)